# Disable a specific output for Eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Eslint's `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` is complaining about a specific package which is working fine. There's no option to ignore a single package for `import/no-extraneous-dependencies`. Is it possible for Eslint to ignore a specific output?

E.g. I want it to ignore:

```
'my-package' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S my-package' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

I don't want it to ignore any other errors produced by `import/no-extraneous-dependencies`.

If I filter lines using `grep` and the only error in a file is the above error, it would leave the file name with no errors underneath.